# cflock do not throw timeout for same url called in same browser

Tags: coldfusion, locking, coldfusion-10, railo, cfml

I am trying lock block on page test.cfm and below is code written on page.

```
<cfscript>
writeOutput("Before lock at #now()#");
lock name="threadlock" timeout="3" type="exclusive"
{
    writeOutput("<br/>started at #now()#");
    thread action="sleep"  duration="10000";
    writeOutput("<br/>ended at #now()#");
}
writeOutput("<br/>After lock at #now()#");
</cfscript>
```

assuming my url for page is http://localhost.local/test.cfm and running it on browser in two different tabs. I was expecting one of the url will throw timeout error after 3 second since another url lock it atleast for 10 seconds due to thread sleep. Surprisingly I do not get any timeout error rather second page call run after 10 seconds as first call finish execution.

But I am appending some url parameter (e.g. http://localhost.local/test.cfm?q=1) will throw error. Also I am calling same url in different browser then one of the call will throw timeout issue.

Is lock based on session and url?

**Update**
Here is output for two different cases:

*Case 1:*

**TAB1** 
Url: http://localhost.local/test/test.cfm

```
 Before lock at {ts '2013-10-18 09:21:35'} 
 started at {ts '2013-10-18 09:21:35'} 
 ended at {ts '2013-10-18 09:21:45'} 
 After lock at {ts '2013-10-18 09:21:45'}
```

**TAB2**
Url: http://localhost.local/test/test.cfm

```
Before lock at {ts '2013-10-18 09:21:45'} 
started at {ts '2013-10-18 09:21:45'}
ended at {ts '2013-10-18 09:21:55'} 
After lock at {ts '2013-10-18 09:21:55'}
```

*Case 2:*

**TAB1** 
Url: http://localhost.local/test/test.cfm

```
 Before lock at {ts '2013-10-18 09:27:18'} 
 started at {ts '2013-10-18 09:27:18'} 
 ended at {ts '2013-10-18 09:27:28'} 
 After lock at {ts '2013-10-18 09:27:28'}
```

**TAB2**
Url: http://localhost.local/test/test.cfm? (Added ? at the end)

```
Before lock at {ts '2013-10-18 09:27:20'} 
A timeout occurred while attempting to lock threadlock.
The error occurred in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/test/test.cfm: line 13
11 : 
12 : <cfoutput>Before lock at #now()#</cfoutput>
13 : <cflock name="threadlock" timeout="3" type="exclusive">
14 :    <cfoutput><br/>started at #now()#</cfoutput>    
15 :    <cfthread action="sleep"  duration="10000"/> 
...
```

Result for case 2 as expected.

For case 1, strange thing I just noticed is tab 2 output "Before lock at {ts '2013-10-18 09:21:45'} indicates that whole request start after 10 seconds (means after the complete execution of first tab) when I have fired it in second URL just after 2 seconds of first tabs.

Comment: No, it do not share session between two different browsers. I mean to say that timeout throw for different session or different url but not only for same url on same session.

Comment: I suspect that it is request based. Each tab is a separate request. The lock on one does not impact the other.

Comment: @JamesMohler, If it is request base then it should generate error after waiting for 3 second, right? but it doesn't

Comment: It sounds like a browser caching issue to me when you open a new tab. That would explain why adding a URL parameter would make it work. Are your output times updating when you open a new tab? Monitor your network traffic when you test this and see if a request is even being sent when you open a new tab.

Comment: Per Peter's comment and link, cflock's name is global and not per request.

Comment: @Miguel-F It can not be caching issue since turned off it in coldfusion.

Comment: @JamesMohler that is right it is global so it should throw timeout error for same url called in different tab of browser.

Comment: @PriteshPatel I don't mean ColdFusion caching, I mean browser caching. As-in, the browser may not even be calling your ColdFusion server when you open a new tab.

Comment: You may want to put a `<cfoutput>#now()#</cfoutput> on the page

Comment: Pritesh: just to confirm, your code works exactly as you expect on my test environment, so the code is solid. Are you hitting the page via a an external web server like Apache or IIS? What if you repeat the experiment using the inbuilt web server that ships with CF? It looks to me like something is single-threading your requests. Can you pls post the exact output from hitting the URL a coupla seconds apart on two different tabs? I just wanna confirm how the output times intermesh, if at all.

Comment: And also please confirm, there is no other code running here other than what you are showing us? Including Application.cfc or similar.

Comment: @Miguel-F It is definitely not browser caching issue since I am printing current time and different everytime. I have updated question with output I am getting for two cases.

Comment: @AdamCameron: I guess that is it, single threading issue. Added output for both cases. And yes, for first case request start after first one finish (watchout "Before lock at..." in output). I am using IIS for CF but I have tried inbuilt webserver for RAILO but same issue. I will try for CF inbuilt.

Comment: Do me a favour... try the code but *without* the lock. Is it still single-threaded?

Comment: yes, I have already tried that...:)
Surprisingly I had not notice output yesterday but just today morning I ran same page realise that and then read your comment. Sometime giving break to mind works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this behavior in Chrome before. If one tab is executing a request to a given URL the other tabs will wait for the first tab to finish and then immediately return.

Here is a proof of concept which I am able to replicate in my Chrome browser consistently.

foo.cfm

```
<cfoutput>#now()#</cfoutput>
<cfscript>
    sleep(5000);
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>#now()#</cfoutput>
```

Open two tabs in your browser to foo.cfm.

**Test1**: Do this next sequence as fast you can without errors. Click tab1, select the URL bar, hit the enter key. Click tab2, select the URL bar, hit the enter key.

When doing that you'll notice that the time stamps in the first page are 5 seconds apart, and you'll notice the timestamp on the second page did not even begin until the first had finished.

**Test2**: Do this next sequence as fast you can without errors. Click tab1, hit ctrl+f5, click tab2, hit ctrl+f5.

Now, notice that tab two will finish nearly right after tab1 and the timestamps indicate that processing took place equal to the duration it took you to switch tabs.

The same behavior occurs if you use f5 as well. So basically it's a micro-optimization of the Chrome browser (and likely others) to not make additional http requests for resources which other tabs are already working on. My supposition, which I have not tested yet, is if the resource were to return proper browser caching HTTP headers, then the second request would use the first requests result.

Comment: OMG, I was thinking it is server (IIS) was doing single threading per client. I have tested further in different browser and Chrome and Firefox has same behavior but IE (yes IE) just work fine and throw error.